# Slow down a JQuery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i am working on an ajax login system for jquery and everything seems to work fine, my question is how am i able to slow down the call or pause for x seconds before the success to show a gif loading image?

code:

```
$('.AJAX').on('submit', function(event) 
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var This = $(this);
    var Data = {};

    This.find('[name]').each(function(Index, Value) {

    var This = $(this),
    Name = This.attr('name'),
    Value = This.val();

    Data[Name] = Value
});

$.ajaxSetup(
{
    beforeSend:function()
    {
        $('.Msg').html('<img src="../Assets/Pictures/Loading.gif" />');
    },
    complete:function()
    {
        $('.Msg').find('img').remove();
    }
});

$.ajax(
{
    url:'Log.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:Data,
    success:function(Data)
    {
        $('.Msg').html('<span style="color:red">' + Data + '</span>').hide().fadeIn('fast');
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: **Don't.**  Adding delay for the sake of a loading animation is [a very bad idea](http://radar.oreilly.com/2009/06/bing-and-google-agree-slow-pag.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use basic setTimeout to delay the action:

```
success:function(Data) {
  setTimeout(function(){
       $('.Msg').html('<span style="color:red">' + Data + '</span>').hide().fadeIn('fast');
  }, 5000); // wait 5 seconds before showing the message
});
```

FYI jQuery [**.delay()**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)  delays the effects in the effects queue. .html() is not an effect so it won't be affected by that method.

Comment: that doesnt work becuase im using $.ajaxSetup to play my gif but this just delays the html.

Comment: Thank you @rochal, I wasn't actually aware of that. `setTimeout` on the single functions I showed in my answer is a good solution.

Comment: Have you considered removing the content of $.ajaxSetup.complete function? Do you really need it considering you are also using success() callback in your ajax call?